# Magento 2 Get product image url by sku

Tags: magento2, product, image

What is the best way to get product image(thumbnail) by sku ?

Comment: Add more details about your task and what want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way the best way to get a product image.

```
protected $_productRepository;

public function __construct(
 \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
) {            
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
}
```

> Get image like this:

```
$product = $this->_productRepository->get($sku); //pass sku here
$product->getData('thumbnail');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: if you getting any error let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

1)Create a block file:

```
<?php
namespace namespace Vendor\Extension\Block;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
class Extension extends Template
{
    protected $imageHelper;
    protected $productFactory;
    public function __construct(Image $imageHelper, ProductFactory $productFactory, Context,) 
    {
        $this->imageHelper = $imageHelper;
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
    }
    public function getProductImageUrl($id)
    {
        try 
        {
            $product = $this->productFactory->create->load($id);
        } 
        catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) 
        {
            return 'Data not found';
        }
        $url = $this->imageHelper->init($product, 'product_thumbnail_image')->getUrl();
        return $url;
    }
}
```

2)Create custom template file:

```
$url=$block->getProductImageUrl($id);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$product = $this->_productRepositoryFactory->create()->getBySku($sku);
$product->getData('image');
```